# Node / Express / Request - Attempt to proxy POST request with parameters throws "Write after end"

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I'm attempting to proxy all /api/ requests from local node server to a remote server while embedding some authentication parameters to them.

My current approach seems to work fine for GET with query parameters and POST as long as I don't give the "form" parameter to Request library, but as soon as I include it, the server starts throwing Error: write after end.

```
var express = require("express");
var request = require("request");
var parser = require("body-parser");
var strftime = require("strftime");

var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var port = 80;
var apiUrl = "http://example.com/";
var apiUser = "example";
var apiPass = "example";

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/dist")));
app.use(parser.json());
app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/api/*/", function(req, res) {
    console.log((strftime("%H:%M:%S") + " | GET -> " + req.url));
    var url = apiUrl + req.url;
    req.pipe(request.get(url, {
        auth: {
            user: apiUser,
            pass: apiPass
        }
    })).pipe(res);
});

app.post("/api/*/", function(req, res) {
    console.log((strftime("%H:%M:%S") + " | POST -> " + req.url));
    var url = apiUrl + req.url;
    req.pipe(request.post(url, {
        form: req.body, // <----- RESULTS IN "write after end" error
        auth: {
            user: apiUser,
            pass: apiPass
        }
    })).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(port);
console.log("Development server started, listening to localhost:" + port);
console.log("Proxying /api/* -> " + apiUrl + "/api/*");
```

This probably has to do with the body-parser middleware, but I couldn't find any fix for this issue and I don't quite get why the "form: req.body" would break the script. Logging the req.body seems to output the expected parameters.

I also attempted the alternative chaining syntax with .form(req.body), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a couple of months old so the OP has probably moved on but I just ran into this and thought I'd post my solution for future searchers. The problem is that request writer is being ended when the reader ends and therefore the body cannot be written (and throws the 'write after end'). So we need to tell it not to end. When passing a body, you need to add { end : false } to the pipe options. For example:

```
app.post("/api/*/", function(req, res) {
    console.log((strftime("%H:%M:%S") + " | POST -> " + req.url));
    var url = apiUrl + req.url;
    req.pipe(request.post(url, {
        form: req.body,
        auth: {
            user: apiUser,
            pass: apiPass
        }
    }), { end : false }).pipe(res);
});
```